# XDMP-ENCODING (err:XQST0087) Unsupport character encoding

Tags: nosql, marklogic

Unable to start MarkLogic service

I installed MarkLogic on RedHat 8. When I try to start the service it says that "Starting MarkLogic" is OK, but I got encoding problem at the end.

```
[root@mlogic]# /sbin/service MarkLogic start
Starting MarkLogic:                                        [  OK  ]
[root@mlogic]#
Broadcast message from systemd-journald@mlogic (Fri 2019-07-26 03:47:51 UTC):

MarkLogic[2671]: Initialization: XDMP-ENCODING: (err:XQST0087) Unsupported character encoding: ascii
```

I also check service status by got this response:

```
[root@mlogic]# service MarkLogic status
MarkLogic dead but pid file exists
```

Then, when I try to stop, it failed

```
[root@mlogic]# /sbin/service MarkLogic stop
Stopping MarkLogic
Stopping MarkLogic: .                                      [FAILED]
```

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: If you have support, this is a good time to use it.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this issue?

Comment: I change the os to Centos and this issue gone.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are seeing is related to the locale setting.  You should ensure the value of **LC_ALL** is set to **"en_US.UTF-8"**.  For an individual user this can be done using the $HOME/.i18n file.  If the file does not exist, please create it and ensure it has the following:

`export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one or more of the prerequisits for the converters are missing. I had this exact same error on the new centos 8.

MarkLogic[7123]: Initialization: XDMP-ENCODING: (err:XQST0087) Unsupported character encoding: ascii

Here are the additional commands I ran.

COMMANDS:

`sudo yum -y install libnsl
sudo yum -y install ncurses-compat-libs
sudo yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64 cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-lib cyrus-sasl-md5 gdb lsb-core-amd64 libtool-ltdl.x86_64
sudo yum -y install libgcc libgcc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686`

Note on reboot, MarkLogic still has this error (in the MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorsLog.txt) and starts up fine but you still cannot not use the service MarkLogic stop or start commands.
Use the following commands instead to start and stop MarkLogic:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
sudo /etc/init.d/MarkLogic stop
sudo /etc/init.d/MarkLogic status
```

Note, I did not have to re-run the rpm -i installation commands.